# ¿Imprimir etiquetas en android mediante Zebra ZQ320 Bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Estoy trabajando en una app mediante android studio, necesito crear una etiqueta e imprimirla mediante la impresora bluetooth Zebra ZQ320. ¿Existe algún tutorial sobre como realizar la conexión y enviar a imprimir a la impresora?

He visto la documentacion del SDK que entrega Zebra pero no lo entiendo muy bien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilice el siguiente codigo que viene en la documentación del ZSDK, este me sirvió para realizar la conexión indicando la dirección mac del bluetooth de la impresora.

```
import android.os.Looper;
```

import com.zebra.sdk.comm.BluetoothConnection;
 import com.zebra.sdk.comm.Connection;

public class BluetoothConnectionExample {

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     BluetoothConnectionExample example = new BluetoothConnectionExample();

     String theBtMacAddress = "00:11:BB:DD:55:FF";
     example.sendZplOverBluetooth(theBtMacAddress);
     example.sendCpclOverBluetooth(theBtMacAddress);
 }

 private void sendZplOverBluetooth(final String theBtMacAddress) {

     new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             try {
                 // Instantiate connection for given Bluetooth&reg; MAC Address.
                 Connection thePrinterConn = new BluetoothConnection(theBtMacAddress);

                 // Initialize
                 Looper.prepare();

                 // Open the connection - physical connection is established here.
                 thePrinterConn.open();

                 // This example prints "This is a ZPL test." near the top of the label.
                 String zplData = "^XA^FO20,20^A0N,25,25^FDThis is a ZPL test.^FS^XZ";

                 // Send the data to printer as a byte array.
                 thePrinterConn.write(zplData.getBytes());

                 // Make sure the data got to the printer before closing the connection
                 Thread.sleep(500);

                 // Close the connection to release resources.
                 thePrinterConn.close();

                 Looper.myLooper().quit();
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 // Handle communications error here.
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
     }).start();
 }
```

Ademas para crear el codigo ZPL necesario utilice una pagina en javascript publicada dentro de un articulo en GitHub, [aqui se los dejo](http://teynon.github.io/ZPL-Label-Designer/index.html).
[El post.](https://github.com/teynon/ZPL-Label-Designer)

Saludos, espero le sirva a alguno :).

Answer (score 0):

```
aqui hay un codigo de prueba para impresion con zebra


package isv.zebra.zebrazq510;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.zebra.sdk.comm.BluetoothConnection;
import com.zebra.sdk.comm.Connection;
import com.zebra.sdk.comm.ConnectionException;
import com.zebra.sdk.comm.TcpConnection;
import com.zebra.sdk.printer.PrinterLanguage;
import com.zebra.sdk.printer.PrinterStatus;
import com.zebra.sdk.printer.SGD;
import com.zebra.sdk.printer.ZebraPrinter;
import com.zebra.sdk.printer.ZebraPrinterFactory;
import com.zebra.sdk.printer.ZebraPrinterLanguageUnknownException;
import com.zebra.sdk.printer.ZebraPrinterLinkOs;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Connection connection;

    private RadioButton btRadioButton;
    private EditText macAddressEditText;
    private EditText ipAddressEditText;
    private EditText portNumberEditText;
    private static final String bluetoothAddressKey = "ZEBRA_DEMO_BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS";
    private static final String tcpAddressKey = "ZEBRA_DEMO_TCP_ADDRESS";
    private static final String tcpPortKey = "ZEBRA_DEMO_TCP_PORT";
    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "OurSavedAddress";

    private Button testButton;
    private ZebraPrinter printer;
    private TextView statusField;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

        ipAddressEditText = this.findViewById(R.id.ipAddressInput);
        String ip = settings.getString(tcpAddressKey, "");
        ipAddressEditText.setText(ip);

        portNumberEditText = this.findViewById(R.id.portInput);
        String port = settings.getString(tcpPortKey, "");
        portNumberEditText.setText(port);

        macAddressEditText = this.findViewById(R.id.macInput);
        String mac = settings.getString(bluetoothAddressKey, "54:6C:0E:01:7F:C8");
        macAddressEditText.setText(mac);


        statusField = this.findViewById(R.id.statusText);


        btRadioButton = this.findViewById(R.id.bluetoothRadio);


        RadioGroup radioGroup = this.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if (checkedId == R.id.bluetoothRadio) {
                    toggleEditField(macAddressEditText, true);
                    toggleEditField(portNumberEditText, false);
                    toggleEditField(ipAddressEditText, false);
                } else {
                    toggleEditField(portNumberEditText, true);
                    toggleEditField(ipAddressEditText, true);
                    toggleEditField(macAddressEditText, false);
                }
            }
        });

        testButton = this.findViewById(R.id.testButton);
        testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        enableTestButton(true);
                        Looper.prepare();
                        doConnectionTest();
                        Looper.loop();
                        Looper.myLooper().quit();
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });


    }


    public ZebraPrinter connect() {
        setStatus("Connecting...", Color.YELLOW);
        connection = null;
        if (isBluetoothSelected()) {
            connection = new BluetoothConnection(getMacAddressFieldText());
            SettingsHelper.saveBluetoothAddress(this, getMacAddressFieldText());
        } else {
            try {
                int port = Integer.parseInt(getTcpPortNumber());
                connection = new TcpConnection(getTcpAddress(), port);
                SettingsHelper.saveIp(this, getTcpAddress());
                SettingsHelper.savePort(this, getTcpPortNumber());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                setStatus("Port Number Is Invalid", Color.RED);
                return null;
            }
        }

        try {
            connection.open();
            setStatus("Connected", Color.GREEN);
        } catch (ConnectionException e) {
            setStatus("Comm Error! Disconnecting", Color.RED);
            DemoSleeper.sleep(1000);
            disconnect();
        }

        ZebraPrinter printer = null;

        if (connection.isConnected()) {
            try {

                printer = ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance(connection);
                setStatus("Determining Printer Language", Color.YELLOW);
                String pl = SGD.GET("device.languages", connection);
                setStatus("Printer Language " + pl, Color.BLUE);
            } catch (ConnectionException | ZebraPrinterLanguageUnknownException e) {
                setStatus("Unknown Printer Language", Color.RED);
                printer = null;
                DemoSleeper.sleep(1000);
                disconnect();
            }
        }

        return printer;
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        try {
            setStatus("Disconnecting", Color.RED);
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
            setStatus("Not Connected", Color.RED);
        } catch (ConnectionException e) {
            setStatus("COMM Error! Disconnected", Color.RED);
        } finally {
            enableTestButton(true);
        }
    }

    private void setStatus(final String statusMessage, final int color) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                statusField.setBackgroundColor(color);
                statusField.setText(statusMessage);
            }
        });
        DemoSleeper.sleep(1000);
    }


    private void sendTestLabel() {
        try {
            ZebraPrinterLinkOs linkOsPrinter = ZebraPrinterFactory.createLinkOsPrinter(printer);

            PrinterStatus printerStatus = (linkOsPrinter != null) ? linkOsPrinter.getCurrentStatus() : printer.getCurrentStatus();

            if (printerStatus.isReadyToPrint) {
                byte[] configLabel = getConfigLabel();
                connection.write(configLabel);
                setStatus("Sending Data", Color.BLUE);
            } else if (printerStatus.isHeadOpen) {
                setStatus("Printer Head Open", Color.RED);
            } else if (printerStatus.isPaused) {
                setStatus("Printer is Paused", Color.RED);
            } else if (printerStatus.isPaperOut) {
                setStatus("Printer Media Out", Color.RED);
            }
            DemoSleeper.sleep(1500);
            if (connection instanceof BluetoothConnection) {
                String friendlyName = ((BluetoothConnection) connection).getFriendlyName();
                setStatus(friendlyName, Color.MAGENTA);
                DemoSleeper.sleep(500);
            }
        } catch (ConnectionException e) {
            setStatus(e.getMessage(), Color.RED);
        } finally {
            disconnect();
        }
    }

    private void enableTestButton(final boolean enabled) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                testButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    }


    private byte[] getConfigLabel() {
        byte[] configLabel = null;
        try {
            PrinterLanguage printerLanguage = printer.getPrinterControlLanguage();
            SGD.SET("device.languages", "zpl", connection);


            if (printerLanguage == PrinterLanguage.ZPL) {

                //para configurar un formato de impresion diseñarlo en la siguiente pagina http://labelary.com/viewer.html

                String bytes = "^XA^FX Top section with company logo, name and address.^CF0,60^FO50,50^GB100,100,100^FS^FO75,75^FR^GB100,100,100^FS^FO88,88^GB50,50,50^FS^FO220,50^FDIntershipping, Inc.^FS^CF0,30^FO220,115^FD1000 Shipping Lane^FS^FO220,155^FDShelbyville TN 38102^FS^FO220,195^FDUnited States (USA)^FS^FO50,250^GB700,1,3^FS^FX Second section with recipient address and permit information.^CFA,30^FO50,300^FDJohn Doe^FS^FO50,340^FD100 Main Street^FS^FO50,380^FDSpringfield TN 39021^FS^FO50,420^FDUnited States (USA)^FS^CFA,15^FO600,300^GB150,150,3^FS^FO638,340^FDPermit^FS^FO638,390^FD123456^FS^FO50,500^GB700,1,3^FS^FX Third section with barcode.^BY5,2,270^FO100,550^BC^FD12345678^FS^FX Fourth section (the two boxes on the bottom).^FO50,900^GB700,250,3^FS^FO400,900^GB1,250,3^FS^CF0,40^FO100,960^FDCtr. X34B-1^FS^FO100,1010^FDREF1 F00B47^FS^FO100,1060^FDREF2 BL4H8^FS^CF0,190^FO470,955^FDCA^FS^XZ";

                configLabel = bytes.getBytes();

            } else if (printerLanguage == PrinterLanguage.CPCL) {
                String cpclConfigLabel = "! 0 200 200 406 1\r\n" + "ON-FEED IGNORE\r\n" + "BOX 20 20 380 380 8\r\n" + "T 0 6 137 177 TEST\r\n" + "PRINT\r\n";
                configLabel = cpclConfigLabel.getBytes();
            }
        } catch (ConnectionException e) {
            Log.e("ConectionExeption",e.getMessage()+" "+e.getCause());
        }
        return configLabel;
    }

    private void doConnectionTest() {
        printer = connect();

        if (printer != null) {
            sendTestLabel();
        } else {
            disconnect();
        }
    }

    private void toggleEditField(EditText editText, boolean set) {
        editText.setEnabled(set);
        editText.setFocusable(set);
        editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(set);
    }

    private boolean isBluetoothSelected() {
        return btRadioButton.isChecked();
    }

    private String getMacAddressFieldText() {
        return macAddressEditText.getText().toString();
    }

    private String getTcpAddress() {
        return ipAddressEditText.getText().toString();
    }

    private String getTcpPortNumber() {
        return portNumberEditText.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: creo que el código de la respuesta anterior esta menos complejo y se entiende de mejor manera para lo que intentaba hacer