# Imprimir tickets con impresora ZEBRA QLn320 Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, impresora, zebra

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación para imprimir tickets en una ZEBRA QLn320. Ya tengo la conexión establecida desde el app a la impresora el tema es que la codificación que encontré es de una ZEBRA ZQ510 y creo que por ello me realiza la impresión en forma de recibo, es lo que pienso.
Lo que quiero es imprimir sólo un ticket con la información que le envío desde la aplicación.
Este el metodo que envío para enviarle el texto a la impresora:

```
private byte[] getConfigLabel() {
    byte[] configLabel = null;
    try {
        PrinterLanguage printerLanguage = printer.getPrinterControlLanguage();
        SGD.SET("device.languages", "zpl", connection);
        if (printerLanguage == PrinterLanguage.ZPL) {
            //para configurar un formato de impresion diseñarlo en la siguiente pagina http://labelary.com/viewer.html
            String bytes = "^XA\n" +
                    "^CF0,30\n" +
                    "^FO70,10^FDHOLA MUNDO^FS\n" +
                    "^CF0,10\n" +
                    "^XZ";
            configLabel = bytes.getBytes();
        } else if (printerLanguage == PrinterLanguage.CPCL) {
            String cpclConfigLabel = "! 0 200 200 406 1\r\n" + "ON-FEED IGNORE\r\n" + "BOX 20 20 380 380 8\r\n" + "T 0 6 137 177 TEST\r\n" + "PRINT\r\n";
            configLabel = cpclConfigLabel.getBytes();
        }
    } catch (ConnectionException e) {
        Log.e("ConectionExeption",e.getMessage()+" "+e.getCause());
    }
    return configLabel;
}
```

Pero me imprime así, adjunto foto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería mucho si me ayudan

Comment: Solo encontré esto no se si te sirva https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/299685/imprimir-etiquetas-en-android-mediante-zebra-zq320-bluetooth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that your printer is configured to use continuous paper (receipt paper) while it has label media installed. That's the reason you see the printer feeds multiple labels just for one line of print ("HOLA MUNDO"). There is nothing wrong with the ZPL you used in the code, and nothing wrong with the encoding.

You need to change the media.type to label on the printer and do a media calibration. The following SGD commands will help.

```
! U1 getvar "media.type"<CR><LF> // Get the currently setting of media.type.

! U1 setvar "media.type" "label"<CR><LF> // Set media.type to label if label media is installed.

! U1 setvar "media.type" "journal"<CR><LF> // Set media.type to journal if receipt media is installed.

~JC // Start media sensor calibration
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. El idioma aquí es español, así que debo pedirte que traduzcas tu respuesta, por favor.